# Is this normal for docker?

Tags: docker

I am building an image that installs ant, maven, phantomjs, grunt-cli but when i run

```
docker build
```

It's takes a while to start sending build context to docker and then the size is

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 7.451 GB
```

Is that normal or is there something I can do to speed this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker build` tars up and transfers the directory where you run it, including all subdirectories. If you want to include less data in the build context (and so speed things up), you should run `docker build` from a directory containing the minimal data for your build.

So `docker build` requires at least a `Dockerfile` and usually you want to include your source code in your local directory (though Docker can pull it from other sources).